# how to run an app using launchd?

Tags: macos, launchd

I need to run an mac app daily without any user interaction using `launchd`, i created a `.plist` file and pasted it in `/system/LaunchDaemons` and after that how to execute the `plist` file, can any one please tell me the step by step working process on how to work with `launchd` it will helpful for me, I pasted my `.plist` file below.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
            <key>RunAtLoad</key>  
            <true/>
            <key>KeepAlive</key>
            <true/>
            <key>Label</key>
            <string>myapp.restart</string>
            <key>ProgramArguments</key>
            <array>
                    <string>/Applications/myapp.app</string>
            </array>
            <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Hour</key>
                <integer>16</integer>
                <key>Minute</key>
                <integer>40</integer>
           </dict>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

Comment: You probably won't be able to do this. Even if the app doesn't require user interaction, it probably needs to be run within the context of a login session, and launch daemons aren't run this way.

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably need the name of your program like this rather than `ProgramArguments`:

```
<key>Program</key>
<string>/Applications/myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp</string>
```

Comment: thank you sir, and i have one doubt i have created a .plist file using text editor and saved it with .plist extension am i doing it right way or should i want to use some other tool to create a .plist file ?

Comment: You can use any editor so long as it doesn't insert RTF or other non-ASCII formatting characters. If you use `Textedit` on the Mac, press `Shift-Cmd-T` until it says `xyz.TXT` in the title bar rather than `xyz.RTF`.

Comment: it doesn't helped me in solving my problem,but today i found the solution and ran it successfully anyway thanks for your commitment